# how can i use rugged to create and commit a file like from the command line?

Tags: ruby, git, libgit2, rugged

i'm trying to use rugged to do something pretty simple: create and commit a file, leaving the repository in the same state as doing:

```
git init
echo "blah blah blah" > blah.txt
git add blah.txt
git commit -m "write blah.txt"
```

which leaves `git status` printing

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

i'm using code adapted from the rugged repo's [readme](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged#writing-to-a-repository), which boils down to:

```
name = "blah.txt"
repo = Rugged::Repository.init_at dir

File.open File.join(dir, name), 'w' do |f|
  f.write content
end

oid = Rugged::Blob.from_workdir repo, name
index = repo.index

index.add(:path => name, :oid => oid, :mode => 0100644)

options = {}
options[:tree] = index.write_tree(repo)

options[:author] = {  :email => "testuser@github.com",
                      :name => 'Test Author',
                      :time => Time.now }
options[:committer] = { :email => "testuser@github.com",
                        :name => 'Test Author',
                        :time => Time.now }
options[:message] =  "write #{ name }"
options[:parents] = repo.empty? ? [] : [ repo.head.target ].compact
options[:update_ref] = 'HEAD'

commit = Rugged::Commit.create(repo, options)
```

this seems to leave the *repository* in the right state, but the *working dir* in a weird place, with `git status` printing

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    blah.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    blah.txt
```

i don't understand what git thinks is happening at this point (`blah.txt` is staged for delete?). executing `git reset --hard` puts the working dir back in the desired state from what i can tell.

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you get with `repo.head`?

Comment: @BroiSatse after the script `repo.head` returns `#<Rugged::Reference:70351778973300 {name: "refs/heads/master", target: #<Rugged::Commit:70351778972640 {message: "write blah.txt", tree: #<Rugged::Tree:70351778972520 {oid: 0066195e7906b164d170885e8c341fd1f1027e3d}>
  <"blah.txt" f0c1bd0931281f8df0574ff2a1e106547b4366cb>
, parents: []}>}>`

Answer (score 4):

You've forgotten to save your changes to the index. You've updated the reference to point to the new commit, but the index is unchanged (as you never call `Index#write`), so as far as git is concerned the deletion is staged because the file is not in the index, just as if you had run `git rm blah.txt`.

Comment: how would i change the above code to fix it? or what code would accomplish it? forgive me, but i don't know much about git internals and am finding zero-to-no documentation on rugged. the above example is adapted from the 'write' example on the project's readme: https://github.com/libgit2/rugged#writing-to-a-repository

Comment: I would add what I said, add a call to `Index#write` to persist your changes to the index to disk, in your code that would be `index.write()`.

Comment: yup, that seems to fix it. any idea why that is missing from the `rugged` docs at https://github.com/libgit2/rugged#writing-to-a-repository? is there some reason you wouldn't want to write the index before making the commit?

Comment: That example does not emulate the git-commit command, it just creates a new commit. An Index is not just the .git/index file but a data structure, it's common to want to use it without affecting the index file.

Comment: ok, so, along the lines of the initial question, how *can* i emulate the `git add ...; git commit` commands? that what i'm trying to do. i notice after adding the `index.write` call, modifications to `blah.txt` do not show up as changes in `git status`, for instance, and i'm guessing from your response there may be more issues as well.

Comment: `git add` would be something like `idx = repo.index; idx.add(String); idx.write`, for commit it depends which options you want to emulate. The simplest form is what it shows in the README, pass a branch you'd like to update.