# Rugged::Repository #status reports a cleared status when using Rugged to add a file to the index

Tags: git, rugged

I am attempting to use Rugged::Index #add to add a new file to the index.
It seems to be successfully added to the index but the associated Rugged::Repository #status
is cleared for the given file.

## Example IRB session showing my attempt to add file "TEST_JJV_IRB1"

```
>> path = "TEST_JJV_IRB1"
=> "TEST_JJV_IRB1"
>> FileUtils.touch("#{local_repo}/#{path}")
=> ["/var/tmp/d20141015-95025-c5bbxe/TEST_JJV_IRB1"]
>> repo.inspect
=> "#<Rugged::Repository:70155837868280 {path: \"/private/var/tmp/d20141015-95025-c5bbxe/.git/\"}>"
```

The newly created file, "TEST_JJV_IRB1", is correctly reported by Rugged::Repository #status

```
>> repo.status(path)
=> [:worktree_new]
```

and correctly not included in the Rugged::Index

```
>> index = repo.index
=> #<Rugged::Index
  [0] 'a_file'
  [0] 'b_file'
  [0] 'c_file'
```

Here I attempt to add the new file to the index.

```
>> oid = Rugged::Blob.from_workdir repo, path
=> "e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391"
>> index.add(:path => path, :oid => oid, :mode => 0100644)
=> nil
>> index.write
=> nil
```

The file being added, "TEST_JJV_IRB1", is now correctly included in the index.

```
>> repo.index
=> #<Rugged::Index
  [0] 'a_file'
  [0] 'b_file'
  [0] 'c_file'
  [0] 'TEST_JJV_IRB1'
```

But it's status reported as cleared by  Rugged::Repository #status

```
>> repo.status(path)
=> []
```

I would expect Rugged::Repository #status to report [:index_new]

Oddly the issuing `git status` from the command line shows the new
file, "TEST_JJV_IRB1", as "Changes to be committed:"

```
% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   TEST_JJV_IRB1
```

Comment: I very well may simply be using Rugged::Index #add incorrectly... ?

Answer (score 0):

Rugged is confusing.

I did notice this is similar to [how can i use rugged to create and commit a file like from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551308/how-can-i-use-rugged-to-create-and-commit-a-file-like-from-the-command-line)

Looking at https://github.com/libgit2/rugged#writing-to-a-repository - It looks like `add` has a second parameter titled `type`. Does this change things?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Rugged is confusing! 
I have read the similar article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551308/how-can-i-use-rugged-to-create-and-commit-a-file-like-from-the-command-line

It looks like repo.write has the type param not index.add. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Rugged is confusing! 
I have read the similar article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551308/how-can-i-use-rugged-to-create-and-commit-a-file-like-from-the-command-line

It looks like repo.write has the type param not index.add or am I missing something?

I have tried the repo.write type param but it seems to have no impact.